# CoRegisterClassObject acess class from different integrity level or privileges

Tags: windows, com, ole, c++-winrt

I'm using WinRT for showing ToastNotification. While working on this, I stumbled across the more generic problem that when a class factor is registered via

```
::CoRegisterClassObject(
        callbackGuid,
        winrt::make<NotificationCallbackFactory>().get(),
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
        REGCLS_SINGLEUSE,
        &registration))
```

from a server process running with admin rights, a client process running with normal rights cannot instantiate it. The call
   `CoCreateInstanceEx(callbackGuid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, pcsi, 1, &mq);` 
fails with error 80040154 Class not registered. I know that from a security standpoint this makes sense, but I was wondering if there is a way to bypass the check without using changing the running privileges of my process and without using global modifiers like CoInitializeSecurity. Basically I need a way to say "this class is accessible to everyone". Also I don't have a AppID.

EDIT: I forgot to say that the final solution must be on the server side, because for the original task of the Toast Notification I have no control on the client

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker

Comment: I forgot to say that the final solution must be on the server side, because for the original task of the Toast Notification I have no control on the client

Comment: Could you please what "**the final solution must be on the server side**" means? You mean you want to elevate the com privileges used by the client from the server side, right?

Comment: Yes, simply I mean that there is no control over the client code, so I cannot implement anything in the client.

Answer (score 1):

COM weighs 3 main factors when deciding whether a running out-of-proc server is visible to a client attempting to activate that server’s CLSID: **the configuration of the CLSID** (typically in the registry), **the server identity** (as described by its token), and **the client identit**y. The main security concern you’re trying to evaluate at that point is not access, as implied by the original question. Access is controlled by launch permissions (part of the CLSID configuration) and access permissions (configured via CoInitializeSecurity), and the server can use those security descriptors to describe which clients are allowed to respectively activate and call them. Those permissions can be made extremely broad, if the server so chooses. But they’re not relevant if the server isn’t even visible to the client.
The security concern you’re dealing with when evaluating activation visibility is actually squatting: can the client trust that the server is who they expect it to be?

If the CLSID configuration describes exactly what the server identity should be (e.g. a RunAs=System CLSID), then COM can reject any servers trying to CoRegister with an inappropriate identity; since there’s no squatting risk to any clients at that point, you can make that server visible to all clients. But at the other extreme, if the CLSID configuration doesn’t constrain the server identity at all, then making the server visible to a broad range of clients would have a significant squatting risk.
That latter case is referred to as “Activate-As-Activator” (AAA), because the server is only visible to the client (i.e. activator) if their identities match. If the CLSID has no configuration at all, or if the configuration doesn’t sufficiently constrain server identity, the CLSID is considered activate-as-activator. Since the server is only visible to clients with sufficiently similar identities, a non-admin client won’t be able to activate an admin server (or vice versa for that matter). You can’t prevent squatting attacks by verifying the server identity for these CLSIDs, so you can only allow activations that don’t cross any security boundary at all.

So if the server is some high-privileged known account such as System or LocalService, you would need to configure the CLSID with a RunAs APPID for that account. If the server’s identity is “**the same as the client’s but elevated**”, you don’t have a RunAs that describes that. What you do have for that case is the elevation moniker. You configure the CLSID as Activate-As-Activator, and add some extra configuration to make it compatible with the elevation moniker. You also need different client code which explicitly activates through the [elevation moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-com-elevation-moniker). And the activation would pop up a UAC prompt. Unfortunately, if you can’t alter the client code, and you’re in that latter “the same as the client but elevated” case, I don’t believe there’s any way to make the activation succeed directly. You could probably introduce another layer to make it work (original CLSID starts up an exe under the client’s token through AAA activation; then that intermediary process does an elevation moniker activation of the real CLSID running as admin). But it would be far cleaner to change the client code.

Comment: What about classes being registered at runtime via CoRegisterClassObject without the registry? I have a low IL process that desires to use a class hosted in a medium IL process (so elevation monikers don't seem right as they seem to be for admin perms only, not ILs).